# Loop through preg_match_all result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to loop through the result of `preg_match_all()` and to replace the matches.

What I am trying to achieve is to extract all the occurrences in a text that is in between curly brackets with a dollar sign in front, and then create a `<span>` with an id that is the content within the curly brackets.

So in the example below from the text "Working from ${spa_open_time} to ${spa_close_time} every day", I should extract `${spa_open_time}` and `${spa_close_time}` and replace them in the text with a `<span>`.

**The expected result**

```
Working from <span id="tag_spa_open_time">${spa_open_time}</span> to <span id="tag_spa_close_time">${spa_close_time}</span> every day
```

**Here is the code I came up with so far**

```
$text = 'Working from ${spa_open_time} to ${spa_close_time} every day';
$result = preg_match_all('/(\$\{\w+\})/', $text, $positive_catch);
if ($result > 0) {
    foreach ($positive_catch as $catch) {
        if (is_array($catch)) {
            foreach ($catch as $key => $ivalue) {
                $fvalue = str_replace("\${", "", $ivalue);
                $fvalue = str_replace("}", "", $fvalue);
                $replace = '<span id="tag_'.$fvalue.'">'.$ivalue.'</span>';
                $str = str_replace($catch,$replace,$text);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    $str = $text;
    }
echo $str;
```

**And the current result is**

```
Working from <span id="tag_spa_close_time"><span id="tag_spa_close_time">${spa_close_time}</span></span> to <span id="tag_spa_close_time">${spa_close_time}</span> every day
```

I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what's the problem.
Here is the code in action http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31894399fd981fb791c587fa04c68581c4945b6d

Comment: @Dorvalla the `$fvalue` is `$ivalue` with the surrounding `${...}` stripped, used for the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make multiple replacements, using [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) is easier and more reliable than looping over the results of a `preg_match_all()` with `str_replace()`.

```
$text = 'Working from ${spa_open_time} to ${spa_close_time} every day';

$text = preg_replace_callback('/(\$\{\w+\})/', function($match) {

        // Removing the leading and trailing characters for class name:
        $fvalue = substr($match[1], 2, -1);

        // Returning the match (your $ivalue) wrapped in a span-tag:
        return '<span id="tag_'.$fvalue.'">' . $match[1] . '</span>';
}, $text);
```

This returns the result you expect. If there are no matches, the `$text` string remains as-is.

Here `preg_replace_callback` both matches all instances of your regular expression, and lets you transform the matches and return them "in-place", without having to separately search/replace over your string. Then, any replacements will happen exactly where they should, which isn't a given with more complex string replacement operations.

Comment: Thanks. Although @kmoser was aligned, with my approach, I find your example indeed much simpler. Thanks a lot and have a Happy Holiday!

Comment: I'm glad it helps, and happy holidays to you too! P.S. If I had to rename favorite PHP functions, `preg_replace_callback` would be somewhere up top on the list. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your regexp to return the strings to search for (e.g. "${spa_open_time}") and the "keys" (e.g. "spa_open_time"). I'm then looping through those arrays concurrently, and generating a pair of search-and-replace strings which I'm applying to `$str`, which gets modified every time. At the end of the loop, `$str` contains your results.

```php
$str = $text = 'Working from ${spa_open_time} to ${spa_close_time} every day';
$result = preg_match_all('/\$\{(\w+)\}/', $text, $positive_catch);

if ($result > 0) {
    for ( $i=0; $i < sizeof($positive_catch[0]); $i++ ) {
        $search = $positive_catch[0][$i];
        $key = $positive_catch[1][$i];
        $replace = '<span id="tag_' . $key . '">' . $search . '</span>';

        $str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
    }
} else {
    $str = $text;
}
echo $str;
```

`

Comment: Thanks, works as expected.  I will mark as accepted @Markus AO solution as it does look more reliable than what I initially had which you fixed perfectly. Have a Happy holiday!

Comment: As a takeaway from this answer, I'd lift the improved regex that captures both the `${...}` and the contents and spares you from modifying the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group `\${(\w+)}/` around the word characters, which will be returned as the second item of the matches array when using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

The full match is the first item in the matches.

**Note** that you don't have to escape the curly's in the pattern.

```
$text = 'Working from ${spa_open_time} to ${spa_close_time} every day';
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\${(\w+)}/', function($matches) {
    return sprintf('<span id="tag_%s">%s</span>',$matches[1], $matches[0]);
}, $text);

echo $text;
```

Output

```
Working from <span id="tag_spa_open_time">${spa_open_time}</span> to <span id="tag_spa_close_time">${spa_close_time}</span> every day
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/9ngje).